# NHibernate how to create sql:on ID=s.PID AND p.Name = 'ABC'

Tags: nhibernate

[NUnit.Framework.Test]
public void Test2()
{
NHibernate.ISession session = Z.Core.NHibernateCore.NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
var crit = session.CreateCriteria("_School");
crit.CreateCriteria("_ListStudent", "__ListStudent", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
crit.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Expression.Eq("__ListStudent.Name", "Abc"));
var list = crit.List();
Console.Write(list.Count);
}

NHibernate:
SELECT * FROM Tst_School this_ left outer join Tst_Student liststud1_ on this_.Guid=liststud1_.Guid WHERE liststud1_.Name = 'Abc'
How to create sql:
SELECT * FROM Tst_School this_ left outer join Tst_Student liststud1_ on this_.Guid=liststud1_.Guid AND liststud1_.Name = 'Abc'

Thanks

Comment: This is about the laziest entry to StackOverflow I have seen. Please wrap the code in tags and explain what is it that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should check WITH clause in HQL. I don't know if it's possible in CriteriaQuery.

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/05/17/nhibernate-2-1-0-hql-with-clause.aspx